# Getting core dump issue while running java bash script

Tags: linux, java, jvm-hotspot

.sh file:

```
time java -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/parser/TypeConverter.decodeType -XX:-UseLoopPredicate -ea -jar file.jar directory DB details
```

The above script is used to upload details from directory from server to DB, but sometimes it core dumps. Getting the following error on logs:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fcd73286d94, pid=21271, tid=140519844833024
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_91-b14) (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.91-b14 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x814d94]  PhaseIdealLoop::build_loop_late_post(Node*)+0x144
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

-XX:-UseLoopPredicate and XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/parser/TypeConverter.decodeType is not able to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in jdk https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8154831, using eclipse,that is being introduced in 8u74 
Donot try to exclude it from compilation -XX:CompileCommand that leads to some other errors. as one you got. Wait for Java to release next update and upgrade your java with that version and you won't face this issue anymore.

Comment: Until then, downgrade because waiting steals a lot of time.